# How to return updated records using Sequel Gem on a bulk update

Tags: ruby, sequel, sequel-gem

I am using the [Sequel](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel) gem to bulk update Users in MySql.

```
users = Users.filter(:id => ids).all
raise if users.nil?

updated_users = Users.filter(:id => addon_ids).update({deleted: 1, moderator_id: moderator_id})
p updated_users
# => 3
```

According to [Sequel documentation](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/sql_rdoc.html),

> "update [and delete] should return the number of rows affected..."

So the behavior above is expected, but my question is, how can I get the Sequel gem to return the updated records instead of the number of affected records?

I am expecting this behavior:

```
users = Users.filter(:id => ids).all
raise if users.nil?

updated_users = Users.filter(:id => addon_ids).update({deleted: 1, moderator_id: moderator_id})
p updated_users
# => [#<Users @values={:id=>1, :moderator_id=>"testuser", :deleted=>1}>, #<Users @values={:id=>2, :moderator_id=>"testuser", :deleted=>1}>, #<Users @values={:id=>3, :moderator_id=>"testuser", :deleted=>1}>]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is what DBs return so Sequel does what the developer expects it to do. Instead do this:

```
users = Users.where(:id => ids)
raise if users.empty?

updated_users = Users.where(:id => addon_ids)
updated_users.update({deleted: 1, moderator_id: moderator_id})
p updated_users
# => [#<Users @values={:id=>1, :moderator_id=>"testuser", :deleted=>1}>, #<Users @values={:id=>2, :moderator_id=>"testuser", :deleted=>1}>, #<Users @values={:id=>3, :moderator_id=>"testuser", :deleted=>1}>]
```

This way you don't assign the number of affected rows to `updated_users`.

Answer (score 0):

For people that might still be looking for this, depending on your database engine you can use `returning`.

```
updated_users = Users.returning.filter(:id => addon_ids).update({deleted: 1, moderator_id: moderator_id})
p updated_users
# => [#<Users @values={:id=>1, :moderator_id=>"testuser", :deleted=>1}>, #<Users @values={:id=>2, :moderator_id=>"testuser", :deleted=>1}>, #<Users @values={:id=>3, :moderator_id=>"testuser", :deleted=>1}>]
```

Docs: http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jeremyevans/sequel/Sequel%2FDataset%3Areturning